# warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor'

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa

so i was working with some new changes to my code and decided to do a clean and build and got all of this bologna...

I recently added a new PU and such to my persistence.xml based on a db just like my first one using netbeans ide and I wad doing some queries when I got an error and decided to do the clean and build.

I'm not sure what could have caused this, I tried looking for anything that would have @SuportedSourceVersion as I was searching for an answer and found something with that.

http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=7184902
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=210286

[Supported source version RELEASE_6 from annotation processor org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor less than source1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23044511/supported-source-version-release-6-from-annotation-processor-org-eclipse-persist)

this is very annoying and upsetting especially when there isn't much documented on this.

Thanks all.

```
warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor' less than -source '1.8'
Note: Creating non-static metadata factory ...
error: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger not found


An annotation processor threw an uncaught exception.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger not found
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor.process(CanonicalModelProcessor.java:407)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:856)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:381)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:370)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:361)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:56)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.main(Main.java:42)
Caused by: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger not found
C:\Users\Konrad\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FB-Style-Page-Slide-Menu\Uploader\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml:3438: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Konrad\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FB-Style-Page-Slide-Menu\Uploader\nbproject\build-impl.xml:956: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Konrad\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FB-Style-Page-Slide-Menu\Uploader\nbproject\build-impl.xml:291: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 9 seconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

[JavaFX8 - sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger not found Exception in NetBeans 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562797/javafx8-sun-util-logging-platformlogger-not-found-exception-in-netbeans-8)

I decided to look at the second issue which I've had once before and I believe I corrected once before due to the link above.

changing this enabled me to fix this.

What's interesting is that when I looked up this error it says it was due to something that shouldn't be done in some cases, so it makes sense that the errors were related.